# How to periodically check if a periodically run task is completed in C#?

Tags: c#

What I am trying to accomplish: I want to run a task every 10 hours. Only if the previous task is finished, I want to start a new task. If previous task was finished abnormally, I want to restart it immediately/sooner than the 10 hour delay.

What I am doing: I have a timerA that runs a task_1 every 10 hours. I also have a timerB that checks every hour if task_1 was completed successfully or abnormally completed.

pseudo code:

```
class
{
    public Task myTask;

    main()
    {
        timerB = new Timer(e => myTask = myMethod(), null, 0, 1hour);
    }

    myMethod()
    {
        if(!myTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            await myTask;
        }
        else if(myTask.IsFaulted)
        {
            timerA.change(0, 10hours);
        }

        timerA = new Timer(
            e => myTask = someMethodThatReturnsTask(),
            null, 0, 10hours);
    }
}
```

My question is: Could someone please explain if instead of having another timerB, is there a way I could check how task completed within timerA and restart the task immediately if it completed abnormally?
How would the sequence of these timer thread work?
Is there generally a better way to accomplish this using C#?

Since I am new to using C#, I would really appreciate any guidance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17021777/4767498

Comment: Even if I use wait for a task, how can I check inside a timer that a task is completed successfully or abnormally? any sample code would be appreciated

Comment: Given the long times involved have you thought about what may happen if the application dies.  Id test using smaller intervals if you value your sanity too.

Comment: use a boolean value. inside your method set boolean value to true whenever the task is done successfully i.e you reach end of the code and you are sure everything worked as expected. other wise that boolean value remains false meaning that the task didnt worked as expected.

Comment: better way is to use `IsFaulted` property of `Task`. inside your task you must throw exception if anything went wrong. so task finishes and `IsFaulted` property of that task is set to true. so you know that the task just failed. if your task does not throw any exception `IsFaulted` property remains false. for more details of the exception you thrown you can use `Exception` property.