# How to determine the task (which using await inside) completed or not?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a simple task in my code.

```
Task taskRestartingService = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                action: async () =>
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(" welcome");
                                if (sToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                                    return;
                               Console.WriteLine(" running ");
                               await Task.Delay(500, sToken);                                      

                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }, cancellationToken: sToken);

            await Task.WhenAll(taskRestartingService);
            Console.WriteLine(" task completed");
```

When I execute the code I am getting the below output.

[image]

you can see that the Task.whenall() is returned immediately and printed the task completed statement but still task running.

so how can I determine the task is fully completed its execution?

update:

When i use task.Run , the output is same,

[image]

Comment: Why are you calling `Task.WhenAll` when you're only providing a single task? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: (But I think I know what's going on here - I suspect there's a duplicate.)

Comment: I have a list of task in my actual code and One of the task used to monitor the time and restart some win service and then again waiting for that time. So this is the story of this task usage. But I want to capture the task is actually completed or not.

Comment: The problem is that the `action` you pass to `StartNew()` returns at the first `await`, so from `StartNew`'s point of view, the method has finished. You could use the [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that takes a `Func<Task>` (and `awaits` that task)  instead, but Daisy's comments still apply

Comment: No, When I use Task.Run() the output remains same

Comment: Remove the `action:` parameter name (that causes the wrong overload to be used)

Comment: Or replace `action:` by `function:`, that's the correct parameter name and the compiler will know what overload to choose

Comment: @RenéVogt, Thanks for your comments.  the action parameter name was a problem. after removing works fine with task,Run().